# Attribute is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. An inspection table and an inspector table.

Every inspection that an inspector does creates a new row in the inspection table with the score that the inspector gave. I want to be able to run a query that will list the average inspection score that each inspector has given in their career.

I tried:

```
    Select Inspector_first_name, Inspector_last_name, avg (score)
        From Inspector inner join inspection
        on inspector.inspector_num = inspection.inspector_num
        Order by inspector_last_name, inspector_first_name asc;
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Inspector.Inspector_First_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an aggregate function all other columns that are retuned in the SELECT list must be included in a GROUP BY clause.

```
Select Inspector_first_name, Inspector_last_name, avg (score)
    From Inspector inner join inspection
    on inspector.inspector_num = inspection.inspector_num
      Group by inspector_last_name, inspector_first_name
    Order by inspector_last_name, inspector_first_name asc
```